# Python syntax issue - TypeError: Required argument 'name' (pos 1) not found

Tags: python, syntax, io, python-2.x

I am trying to separate some files by their contents and my code looks like this
and it keeps showing me the error.

```
__author__ = 'Sahil Nagpal'

from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("GEOTRELLIS").getOrCreate()
sparkcont = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setAppName("GEOTRELLIS"))
logs = sparkcont.setLogLevel("ERROR")



imageFile = "/mnt/imagefile/IMGFileCopy.txt"
one_meter_File = "/mnt/imagefile/one_meter/one_meter_file.txt"
_13_File = "/mnt/imagefile/13_meter/_13_File.txt"
ned19_File = "/mnt/imagefile/ned19/ned19_File.txt"

#iterate over the file
try:
    with open(file=imageFile,mode="r+") as file, open(file=one_meter_File,mode='w+') as one_meter_File,open(file=_13_File,mode='w+') as _13_File,open(file=ned19_File,mode='w+') as ned19_File:

        for data in file.readlines():
            if("one_meter" in data):
                #writing the one_meter file
                one_meter_File.write(data)
            elif("_13" in data):
                # writing the _13 file
                _13_File.write(data)
            elif("ned19" in data):
                # writing the ned19 file
                ned19_File.write(data)


        one_meter_File.close()
        _13_File.close()
        ned19_File.close()
        file.close()
    print("File Write Done")

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File Not Found")

#spark-submit --master local[*] project.py
```

I am having this error

```
with open(file=imageFile,mode="r+") as file, open(file=one_meter_File,mode='w+') as one_meter_File,open(file=_13_File,mode='w+') as _13_File,open(file=ned19_File,mode='w+') as ned19_File:
TypeError: Required argument 'name' (pos 1) not found
```

Can somebody please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
the built-in function `open` doesn't take the file as a keyword argument, it needs to be set directly, your error says that the required argument "name" isn't found, it's because you need to set the name of your files directly and not as a keyword argument

i.e : `open(one_meter_File, 'w+')`

**Edit in case of people reading this :** 
As stated in the comments this error only happens on python 2 because python 3 handles kwargs as normal args if the key name is right. So proofcheck your python installation, or correct it to python 2 needs, [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) are the python 2 docs for `open`

Comment: Magic is the word for your answer!

Comment: altho, note that this is a python 2 error, so strange that this is happening to you on python 3, what version and IDE are you using if i can ask ? (as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) the required argument is called "name" only in python 2)

Comment: Yes, actually now understand what was the problem.
I was running my code on an AWS cluster and the default python installed and the default environment variable on the cluster is always python 2.7 instead of Python 3.  So for that i initially need to set the version to 3 or above.
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.4

Comment: Okay, for python 3 it should work as even if you're using keyword argument for a required argument, the interpreter is intelligent enough to interpret it right. Actually i was tricked with your tag

Comment: was that an unuseful question?
If no then raise a number nenri :)

Comment: It's an useful one, but people will have to read those comments to understand why it's happening, if they are in the same position (I edited my answer for that)